# How to solve this scenario with Java Spark Hadoop: big text file and need to get filename

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm a student, this is my first project on Spark.
I'm working on a project that aim to find pattern to discover diseases in a large DNA dataset.
I'm using Java 7, Hadoop 2.5.1 and Spark 1.3.1

Before writing the question, I introduce you the scenario and what i did until now.

I need to create a matrix that has samples in rows and attributes in columns.
To identify each row I need in the first column the filename. To classify each row I need a to specify if the sample is a case or a control, this information is recovered from file name. So that recovering file name is a must.

Matrix has to be create from different text files, each one represents a sample. Each file has attributes listed in a column. So I need to transpose this column in order to use it in the matrix (but this should be simple).

Last important thing, each text file has a size > 100MB.

Here's what I did.
I started using `textFile` method, but after many hour spent on google, I understand that there's no way to get filename.
The I tried using `wholeTextFiles` method, everything works perfect with small files, but when I tried it with files of 100Mb each, I got a memory heap error.
Last thing I did was to use `newAPIHadoopFile`, but I found it very tough to use, and I did't find good documentations.

Has someone had a problem like this? Does someone have a good tip to solve this situation?

Thanks

Comment: `textFile` gives you an RDD whose items are the lines of the file. `wholeTextFiles` gives you an RDD of pairs where the value is the entire file content. What is your RDD item supposed to be?

Comment: RDD of pairs is the best solution, with path and the entire text. I wrote the code in Java and it works only with small file. When I use it with 4 files of 100MB size, it returns me memory heap size error. I'm looking for a way to remove memory limit.

Comment: Well, the problem is that each RDD item has to be in a single executor's memory. In fact, each RDD *partition* has to exist in a single executor's memory. So you either have to set a larger heap size on the executors, or you have to partition your data into very few items in each partition. Also note that if you're running this in local mode rather than cluster, then you're bound by the heap size of your driver program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I understand in my case probably is better to partition data into few items in each partition. Because I need to work on 1 or 2 thousand files (more than 100GB total), and I think is not smart to set a larger heap. Correct? Fortunately I'm running on cluster with 54 nodes each with a memory of 128GB.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. The question is whether the smaller data makes sense to you. If you need the entire file then that's what you need, and it's not a problem to create partitions of just a few items of 100MB each (this will not be a problem for big nodes like that) - but you need to request that memory from your executors. If, on the other hand, you can perform your operation just as well with single lines, then that would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RealSkeptic suggestions, I resolved this issue.
I used `wholeTestFiles` method to create RDD Pairs with path and the entire content. Then I've modified `spark-submit` command by adding and setting these two parameters: `--executor-memory 20G` and `--total-executor-cores 10`.